# How to pinpoint the events of document shape changes in a Mongo collection?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

In MongDb, I am recording a set of data from an entry which changes its shape overtime. Some keys get added and removed to/from the collection. How would I pinpoint happening those change events in a large collection?

e.g.

```
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo096", "Age" : 32 }
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo097", "Age" : 22 }
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo098", "Age" : 72 }
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo099", "Age" : 33 }
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo100", "Age" : 32 , "mood": "good"}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo101", "Age" : 22 , "mood": "bad "}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo102", "Age" : 31 , "mood": "fine"}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo103", "Age" : 20 , "mood": "good"}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo104", "Age" : 32 , "mood": "good"}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo105", "Age" : 92 , "stressLevel": "High"}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo106", "Age" : 38 , "stressLevel": "Low "}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo107", "Age" : 42 , "stressLevel": "Aver"}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo108", "Age" : 28 , "stressLevel": "High"}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo109", "mood": "fine"}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo110", "mood": "good"}
{ "_id" : ..., "Name" : "foo111", "mood": "fine"}
```

I would like to ideally get some sort of a result -such as below- telling me:

my Collection's shape changed in the following events and even better to point out the changes.

- `Name: "foo100" => (+)mood`
- `Name: "foo105" => (+)stressLevel, (-)mood`
- `Name: "foo109" => (-)stressLevel, (-)Age`

Comment: Here is one tool  [3T Data Compare & Sync tool](http://3t.io/blog/diff-mongodb/) may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some codes to compare two objects

```
function arr_diff (a1, a2) {
    var a = [], diff = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        a[a1[i]] = '-';
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
        if (a[a2[i]] === '-') {
            delete a[a2[i]];
        } else {
            a[a2[i]] = '+';
        }
    }

    for (var k in a) {
        diff.push(a[k] + k);
    }

    return diff;
};

function compareObjects(o1, o2) {
    var k1 = Object.keys(o1); 
    var k2 = Object.keys(o2); 
    print(arr_diff(k1, k2));
}
```

Then we can do it in one collection as below with the help of the above functions.

```
> var prevDoc = null;
> db.collection.find().forEach(function(curDoc) {
    if (prevDoc) {
        compareObjects(prevDoc, curDoc);
    }
    prevDoc = curDoc;
});
```

Node: To bring your function in the scope in Mongo you need to save the 1st code in a JavaScript file (`foo.js`) and feed it to Mango using `load("foo.js")` function.

Comment: @Mehrad, `a growing single document`? which should be compared with? Sorry, I am confused with it...

Comment: @Mehrad, Also mongodb is schemaless, IMHO, to get the document changes  could be done through compare two document.

Comment: I am sorry zangw. I am quite new with Mangodb and actually been using the terminology wrong. I have used the work **Document** wrong and should've said **Collection** instead. I would like to compare different documents in a single collection and pin point when the structure changed. I will edit the question. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Mehrad, Yes, what I mentioned is different documents in one collection. Sorry to confuse you with my unclear comments...

Comment: zangw, this is quite a neat answer actually. I have been leaning towards a solution which involves **MapReduce**, however, I can easily embed this functionality in one and use it. Cheers

Comment: Was a minor error in the code. with `prevDoc=curDoc` being in the `if` statement, `prevDoc` would never get populated. have fixed it for you.